# How to draw a transparent section within an opaque area

Tags: python, wxpython, transparent

How would you go about cutting a transparent hole into the background of a wxpython window?

Would I have to draw the non transparent area manually, leaving a hole, instead of being able to use a background colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapting my answer to your previous question, though I'm not sure if this meets your needs 100%. Let me know?

Basically we're leaving the previous screen contents intact by not erasing the background. Then we handle the paint events and only draw on certain portions of the screen.

You could switch back to using `SetTransparent` if you need the drawn portions to be translucent and not opaque.

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(None)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
    def OnEraseBackground(self, event):
        pass # do nothing
    def OnLeftDown(self, event):
        print event.GetPosition()
    def OnKeyDown(self, event):
        if event.GetKeyCode() == wx.WXK_ESCAPE:
            self.Close()
        else:
            event.Skip()
    def OnPaint(self, event):
        w, h = self.GetSize()
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        region = wx.RegionFromPoints([(0, 0), (w, 0), (w, h), (0, h)])
        box = wx.RegionFromPoints([(100, 100), (500, 100), (500, 500), (100, 500)])
        region.SubtractRegion(box)
        dc.SetClippingRegionAsRegion(region)
        dc.DrawRectangle(0, 0, w, h)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.ShowFullScreen(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was going for. Thanks for the fantastic answers!

Comment: One quick question. How would I go about drawing a semi-transparent colour in the area around the subtracted region? Is there a brush setting that will let me do that?

Comment: Basically what I'm going for is this, but with the cut-out section completely transparent: https://gist.github.com/1079194  Would I have to do something like have the background in a separate window in order to have the cut-out fully transparent and the surrounding area semi-transparent?

Comment: Hmm, thinking about it... will get back to you.

Comment: What happens if you try this before `DrawRectangle`?... `dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(wx.Colour(0, 0, 0, 128)))` - I'm on a Mac now and can't test on Windows. None of this really works properly on the Mac.

Comment: No joy.. although I don't see why setting an alpha on the colour wouldn't work. In what situations does it work then? It's disappointing to hear that this isn't working on MAC. I was trying to go for something completely cross-platform. Is it just the overriding of the background erasing function that doesn't work?